# Constructor for a class within a class

Tags: c++, class, oop, constructor, nested

I have 2 classes, `Date` and `Employee`.

```
//Date
class Date
{
private:
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
public:
    Date (int, int, int);
    void setDate (int, int, int);
    int getDD();
    int getMM();
    int getYY();
};

//Employee
class Employee
{
private:
    int ID;
    string qualification;
    double salary;
    Date DOB;
    Date dateJoined;
public:
    Employee();
    void setEmployee (int, string, double, Date, Date);
    Date getDOB();
    Date getDateJoined();
    string getQualification();
    void displayEmployee();
};
```

This is my constructor for `Employee` class.

```
Employee::Employee()
{
    ID = 0;
    qualification =" " ;
    salary=0.0;
    Date DOB();
    Date dateJoined();
}
```

I got error C2512: 'Date' : no appropriate default constructor available.

How do I initialize `DOB` and `dateJoined` inside the `Employee` class?

Comment: technically speaking `Date` is not nested in your `Employee` class, it is used for declaring a variable member. if you were to move `class Date {};` inside of `class Employee {};` it would be nested.

Comment: `Date DOB();` I don't know what this is supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that before the `Employee` constructor body is entered, all of the data members are constructed. In this instance, `DOB` and `dateJoined` need to be default-initialized, but there is no default constructor for your `Date` class. Your two main options are to add a default constructor for `Date`, or to initialize those members in the `Employee` constructor initializer list.

Option 1:

```
class Date
{
    Date (); //define this somewhere
};
```

Option 2:

```
Employee::Employee() :
    ID(0),
    qualification(" "),
    salary(0.0),
    DOB(/*some data, maybe taken in as constructor args*/),
    dateJoined(/*ditto*/)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this modification. You need a constructor `Date()`:

```
class Date
{
private:
    int dd;
    int mm;
    int yy;
public:
    Date () {return;}
    Date (int, int, int);
    void setDate (int, int, int);
    int getDD();
    int getMM();
    int getYY();
};
```

Another solution is:

```
Employee::Employee():
   DOB(0,0,0),
   dateJoined(0,0,0)
{
    ID = 0;
    qualification =" " ;
    salary=0.0;
}
```

Comment: The `return;` isn't necessary.

Comment: Yes, Is true! I inserted it to suggest the idea to insert some simple code in place of it! Thanks for the editing! :)

Comment: In fact what he need is to initialize member variables using existing constructor, not another constructor in Date class.

Comment: I added another solution in the reply above! :)

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone now, but when displaying DOB and datejoined, another error appeared. `void Employee::displayemployee()
{
 cout<<"Employee ID: "<<ID<<", "<<qualification<<", $"<<salary<<", Date of Birth: "<<DOB<<", Date Joined: "<<dateJoined;
} ` the error is error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Date' (or there is no acceptable conversion), did i write it wrong??

Comment: The problem is to call the constructor in the way the class Date expects!!! You don't make this!!! :) The solution is to call an existing constructor with all the parameters or to add a new constructor! ;) ... Thank you boys!

Comment: Your second solution won't work because the members will be default-initialized before the construtor body is entered.

Comment: TartanLlama, I'm a C programmer, I use C++, but have some trouble! Are you saying that also if I don't use the initialization in the constructor declaration there will be a default initialization? ...

Comment: If you don't mention the member in the initialization list, it will be default-initialized.

Comment: Yes I understand!!! You are right! Now I will correct all!!! ... I have written a good fake!!! :)

Comment: I hope now is good! ... For the other value, I think, is about the same then, to avoid a copy of your code, I leave the other variables in the constructor ...

Comment: I hear the exclamation marks are on sale. I'll have 300 on my debit card, please